# How can I prove that $A \setminus (B \setminus C) = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap C)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm a high school student who takes courses of computer science with my spare time, this time I take Discrete mathematics, and we have this question (in the header), and I can't really understand how to solve it.

I know that to prove equality between two sets we need to prove that each set is contained in the other set (both sides).

so I need to take some x that is an element of one of the sets and prove that it is also an element in the other set, I tried it, but I keep getting stuck when I get to the point that if x is in A(B\C), that means that x is in A and it is not in (B\C), how can I get from here to the point that x is also in the other set?

same goes for the other direction, I keep getting stuck.

Please forgive me for my English as it is not my primary language. Please forgive me for not writing in pure math (like x in ...) I just don't know how to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $A - B$ as $A\cap \lnot B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \notin (B\setminus C) $ is the same as ~$(x \in B$ and $x \notin C)$.

Distribute the negation and it becomes ($x \notin B$ or $x \in C$).

Comment: hey, can I just say that like this? they are very sensitive when it comes to definitions

Comment: ~(P and Q) is mathematically equivalent to (~P or ~Q) — you can check with a truth table if you want — so yes, what I wrote is logically sound.